# combining soul package and color one in a newcommand

Tags: macros, packages, highlighting, soul

I have to use `\st` (from `soul` package) for crossing a line over a word in a text file. In addition, for presenting a specific replaced word instead of the first one, I use `{\color{blue} second word}`.

For example: `\st{handling} {\color{blue}studding} of very large`.

In order to be similar as below image:

[image]

How can I compress two commands (`\st` and afterward `\color`) in only one command to gain similar output? (For example, `\command{first-word, second word} of very large`

Comment: `\newcommand{\command}[2]{\st{#1}\ \textcolor{blue}{#2}}` and the usage is `\command{handling}{studding}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define a new command using `\newcommand\macroname[<arg count>]{<replacement>}` (arguments are used by `#<num>`, up to 9 arguments are supported), to get an a bit more powerful interface you can load the `xparse` package and use `\NewDocumentCommand`. The following defines a macro that takes a mandatory argument, followed by an optional one specifying the colour and another mandatory argument. The first will be stroked out and the latter will be coloured:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \replacing { m O{blue} m }
  {%
    \st{#1}
    \textcolor{#2}{#3}%
  }

\begin{document}
an appropriate \replacing{handling}{studding} of very large.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different colour can be used with `\replacing{handling}[red]{studding}`.

**EDIT:** A variant that has a coloured line for the strike. It has another optional argument, you can specify the line colour with `\replacing[green]{handling}[red]{studding}`.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \replacing { O{red} m O{blue} m }
  {%
    \begingroup
    \setstcolor{#1}%
    \st{#2}%
    \endgroup
    \space
    \textcolor{#3}{#4}%
  }

\begin{document}
an appropriate \replacing{handling}{studding} of very large.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your instruction. Can you tell me how I change the color of line for instance red instead of black?